# Set timezone React-Datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using the [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) to let user select a date. However, right now it uses local time (PDT), but I want to hardcode it to use a specific timezone (PST).

I tried using `utcOffset` prop but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

For my part I set the defaultTimezone before rendering the React-dates plugin.
React-dates will just use the default timezone.

```
moment.tz.setDefault('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: Make sure to use `import moment from 'moment-timzeone` rather than just `import moment from 'moment'`. I made this mistake and was very confused why it wasn't working.

Comment: where to put this `moment.tz.setDefault('America/Los_Angeles')` I put in my DateInput Component, but it's not working..

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
import React, { ComponentProps } from "react"
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker"
import moment from "moment"

interface Props {
  timezone: string
}

const DatePickerWithTimezone = ({
  selected,
  onChange,
  timezone,
  ...props
}: Props & ComponentProps<typeof DatePicker>) => (
  <DatePicker
    selected={selected ? setLocalZone(selected, timezone) : null}
    onChange={(v, e) => {
      onChange(v ? setOtherZone(v, timezone) : null, e)
    }}
    {...props}
  />
)

const setLocalZone = (date: Date, timezone: string) => {
  const dateWithoutZone = moment
    .tz(date, timezone)
    .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS")
  const localZone = moment(dateWithoutZone).format("Z")
  const dateWithLocalZone = [dateWithoutZone, localZone].join("")

  return new Date(dateWithLocalZone)
}

const setOtherZone = (date: Date, timezone: string) => {
  const dateWithoutZone = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS")
  const otherZone = moment.tz(date, timezone).format("Z")
  const dateWithOtherZone = [dateWithoutZone, otherZone].join("")

  return new Date(dateWithOtherZone)
}

export default DatePickerWithTimezone
```

Comment: Nice! It gets a bit simpler if you use the `date-fns-timezone` library which provides `convertToLocalTime(date, { timeZone: timezone })` and `convertToTimeZone(date, { timeZone: timezone })` which work essentially the same way that your `setLocalZone` and `setOtherZone` functions do.

Answer (score 5):

since datepicker doesn't use moment.js anymore i tried to implement a hacky solution for this issue, assuming the initial value is a string for instance:

```
export const formatUTC = (dateInt, addOffset = false) => {
    let date = (!dateInt || dateInt.length < 1) ? new Date : new Date(dateInt);
    if (typeof dateInt === "string") {
        return date;
    } else {
        const offset = addOffset ? date.getTimezoneOffset() : -(date.getTimezoneOffset());
        const offsetDate = new Date();
        offsetDate.setTime(date.getTime() + offset * 60000)
        return offsetDate;
    }
}
```

inside date i call the formatter like this:

```
selected={formatUTC(this.props.input.value,true)}
                    onChange={date => formatUTC(date)}
```

Comment: this works for me. should have marked as correct

Answer (score 1):

I've been thru this, If you decided that you want to just ignore your local offset then you can hardcode the zone. 
**Observation just to give a complete answer:** PST will always be -08:00, but if you want for example pacific time, right now is -07:00, in this case, you may want to install 'moment.timezone' then `import moment from 'moment-timezone'` and just get the current offset with `moment.tz('US/Pacific').format('Z')`

**The code in typescript (I can change it to Javascript if you want):**

```
interface ICalendarInputProps {
  handleChange: (newDate: moment.Moment) => void;
}

const CalendarInput = ({ handleChange }: ICalendarInputProps) => {
  const onChange = (date: Date) => {
    handleChange(moment(`${moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss')}-08:00`));
    // This is to get the offset from a timezone: handleChange(moment(`${moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss')}${moment.tz('US/Pacific').format('Z')}`));
  };

  return (<DatePicker onChange={onChange} />);
};

export default CalendarInput;
```

Comment: Just a note.. rather than hh - use HH (24hr time) in the format call - otherwise you will always return time as am.

`${moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')}-08:00`)

Answer (score 1):

This component outputs Date objects set to midnight local-time at the start of the chosen day. This is a problem. If there is a way of configuring this behaviour, I haven't found it.

The only way to stay sane when dealing with dates is to make sure that your dates are always *midnight UTC* at the start of the date in question. To get this behaviour from react-datepicker, the only thing I've found is to subtract the timezone offset from the output...

```
interface IProps {
  value: any
  setValue: (value: Date) => void
}

const DayPicker: FC<IProps> = ({ value, setValue, placeholderText = "", minDate = new Date() }) => {
  function correctToUtcThenSet(val: Date) {
    setValue(new Date(val.getTime() - val.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000))
  }
  return <DatePicker
    onChange={correctToUtcThenSet}
    selected={value}
  />
}
```

Comment: sucks this is the way everyone is doing this, Its really the only solution ive found aswell. Feels so hacky and wrong. But if it works it works

Answer (score 0):

Other answers didn't work as I'd hoped, and sometimes the dates were off by 1 day because of time zone differences.

This is what I needed:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import { getEndOfDayUtc, treatLocalDateAsUtcMidnight, treatUtcMidnightAsLocalDate } from '../../../shared/helpers/datetime';

type DatePickerUtcProps = {
  selected: Date | string;
  onChange: any;
  isEndOfDay: boolean;
};

function getSelectedAsLocal(selected: Date | string): Date {
  const selectedDate = typeof selected === 'string' ? new Date(selected) : selected;

  return treatUtcMidnightAsLocalDate(selectedDate);
}

export function DatePickerUtc({ selected, onChange, isEndOfDay, ...datePickerProps }: DatePickerUtcProps): JSX.Element {
  function onChangeAsUtc(local: Date) {
    const utc = treatLocalDateAsUtcMidnight(local);
    const adjusted = isEndOfDay ? getEndOfDayUtc(utc) : utc;
    console.log('onChangeAsUtc', { local, utc, adjusted, isEndOfDay });
    onChange(adjusted);
  }

  return <DatePicker onChange={onChangeAsUtc} selected={getSelectedAsLocal(selected)} {...datePickerProps} />;
}
```

```
export function treatLocalDateAsUtcMidnight(localDate: Date): Date {
  const moment = dayjs(localDate).tz('UTC', true); // https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/timezone
  const utcMidnight = getStartOfDayUtc(moment.toDate());
  console.log({ localDate, utcMidnight });
  return utcMidnight;
}

export function treatUtcMidnightAsLocalDate(utcMidnight: Date): Date {
  const sliceOfJustTheDatePart = utcMidnight.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  const localDate = dayjs(sliceOfJustTheDatePart).toDate();

  console.log({ localDate, sliceOfJustTheDatePart, utcMidnight });
  return localDate;
}
```

```
From: <DatePickerUtc selected={startDate} onChange={(utcDate: Date) => setStartDate(utcDate)} {...datePickerProps} />
To: <DatePickerUtc selected={endDate} onChange={(utcDate: Date) => setEndDate(utcDate)} {...datePickerPropsEndOfDay} />
```

Answer (score -1):

I also didn't have luck with `utcOffset`. You could use `moment-timezone` in your project instead of `moment` and convert it yourself:

```
import moment from "moment-timezone";

onDateChange = date => {
  console.log("as is:", date.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
  console.log("PST:", moment(date).tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
};
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/y2vwj9mwpz

Answer (score -4):

Since you're using moment.js, you can try using `moment.utc()` and subtract hours to pst timezone.

```
moment.utc().startOf('day').subtract(8, 'hours')
```