# How to set timezone in react date-picker

Tags: reactjs, datetime, momentjs, react-datepicker

I am working on one react application .In this react application i am using a `react-datepicker` to show the time. I am receiving time in milliseconds . I need to convert that in a particular time zone. How can i achieve that.I want to convert this selected time into one particular time-zone not into the browser zone

```
<DatePicker
                
                timeIntervals={5}
                onKeyDown={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                }}
                timeCaption="time"
                dateFormat="h:mm aa"
                selected={1652905200000}
            
                
              />
```

Comment: Seems like that someone already asked something similar see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052012/set-timezone-react-datepicker

Comment: This solution is not working